# Python 2.7.8 print to one line without comma

Tags: python, debugging

I keep getting the same error message but I have no idea what the error is trying to tell me.

```
# from __future__ import print_function
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

# unpack the arguments
filename = argv

print("Checking if %s exists" % filename, sep='', end='')
```

Here is the error.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "check.py", line 8
    print("Checking if %s exists" % filename, sep='', end='')
                                                 ^
```

The syntax looks correct according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print). I have tried removing the parenthesis, I have tried `import __future__.print_function` in hopes this might help. I don't know what else to do. Thanks for the help, the whole program is below.

```
# Program checks if file exists. Prints out textual interface
# gives the impression of "loading".
from __future__ import print_function
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
from time import sleep

# unpack the arguments
script, filename = argv

print("Checking if %s exists" % filename, sep='', end='')

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        sleep(1)
        print( ".", sep='', end='')
    print( "\b\b\b", sep='', end='')

print
print("File exists: %s" % exists(filename) )
```

Comment: Are you sure? Your code works for me (if I uncomment the first line).

Comment: Unrelated, but `filename = argv` probably doesn't “unpack the arguments” the way you expect it.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I guess I panicked there. This is not the whole program. I took out a irrelevant parts to post the problem.

Comment: Your complete program also works for me (I'm running Python 2.7.6). One suggestion I would make is doing `print()` for the second to last line, instead of `print`. The latter does nothing, the former prints a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options, but you need to use them correctly.

Firstly, if you use `from __future__ import print_function`, you **must** use parenthises for `print()`.  That import changes Python 2's `print` to be just like the Python 3 version.  This is only for the Python 2.x interpreter.  Python 3, of course, already has `print()`.

Adding a comma to the end of `print` only works with the Python 2.x style of `print`.  It doesn't make sense with the Python 3 style of `print()`.

With that in mind, you have two options.

1. Python 3 style: `print("some text", end='')`
2. Use `sys.stdout`: `sys.stdout.write("some text")`

Both options work in Python 2.7 (with `from __future__ import print_function`), and Python 3.

Here's an example which includes the `"%s" % X` you are using.  Also note that that style has been deprectated in Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys


def print_no_newline_1(text):
    sys.stdout.write("the text is [%s]" % text)


def python3_style(text):
    print("the text is [%s]" % text, end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_no_newline_1("my text")
    print("  this will be on the same line")

    python3_style("my text")
    print("  this will be on the same line")
```

The output of this script, in both Python 2 and Python 3, is:

```
the text is [my text]  this will be on the same line
the text is [my text]  this will be on the same line
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print "Checking if %s exists" % filename
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're using `sep=''` and `end=''` for.

[edit: fix missing double-quote]

Comment: It's a Python 3 thing.

Comment: That's what I figured since his syntax was Python 3.  I had just never seen it before.